# Schedule script execution after fixed time?

Tags: python, scheduling, jobs, scheduler

I have a Python script that can run anywhere from 10 seconds to 5 minutes.

I need a scheduler that can spawn the job, then after the job is finished, wait 15 minutes, then run the job again etc.

- No concurrency, just one instance of the job.
- After the job is finished (not started!) there must be a wait period of 15 minutes.
- Linux machine.

Comment: Any reason you're not using cron?

Comment: I haven't found in the documentation how to batch the job AFTER the current running job is finished, i.e. not in fixed intervals. Any pointers?

Comment: That's an odd requirement to have and something I don't know how to do in cron.  The answer below with the little bash script would work fine or the equivalent logic in your python code. That's actually a pretty common approach for apps that do any polling.  Another approach would be for your python script to reschedule itself as it finishes for 15 minutes later using the unix `at` command and the `time` module to calculate an offset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a bash script to do that. Invoke the program then after it finishes sleep for 15 minutes.

```
while true; do
    python myprogram.py
    sleep 900
done
```